# Split comment in multiple comments - allowed or not?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Is it ok to split a comment into multiple comments to bypass the 600 chars limit (if needed)?

If yes, why to put a limit at all? Why not removing this limit (apart from technical reasons)?

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens. 

They should not be used to answer. If you exceed the limit then you are misusing them.

Comment: Well yes you can technically do this, but why? If you have a comment that's so long then it might be more of an answer than a comment. Comments are primarily for requesting clarification on a post, and that rarely takes 600 characters to do so.

Comment: the assumption to which a 600+ chars text will ALWAYS answer the question is just plain wrong. I'm just talking about comments here: not answers.

Comment: _'If you exceed the limit then you are misusing them.'_ ... _'then it might be more of an answer than a comment'_ But not necessarily - _might_ even be best to just say nothing at all. Length does not dictate value as an answer.

Comment: @juergen d: What if they aren't answers?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Then I would say it contains a lot of noise.

Comment: @juergend Yet another potentially dangerous assumption and generalisation.

Comment: On Drupal Answers I've seen mods doing it to explain newcomers errors of their ways.

Answer (score 8):

You generally don't need to be writing such long-winded comments; 500 characters is quite a generous limit most of the time. If you're posting something that's very long, *chances are* it's more suited as an edit or a post in its own right.

Of course, that isn't *always* the case. If I do have something to say that isn't appropriate to post as an answer, but does serve well as commentary, I will post it as a multi-part comment. I don't do this very often though, again because I don't usually need that many characters. And as a moderator I usually leave such comments alone unless they actively detract from the topic at hand. But this is just my take.

Answer (score 6):

This is a quote from Jeff Atwood taken from [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html), emphasis are mine:

> At Stack Exchange, one of the tricky things we learned about Q&A is that if your goal is to have an excellent signal to noise ratio, you must suppress discussion. Stack Exchange only supports the absolute minimum amount of discussion necessary to produce great questions and great answers. That's why answers get constantly re-ordered by votes, **that's why comments have limited formatting and length and only a few display**, and so forth.